# How can I select a row, then UPDATE it if it's column value =x, while also using the row with an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

In this scenario I have 2 tables: a task_pool table and an orders table.

**task_pool**

| task_id (key) | order_id(int) | status(int) | expire_time(timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | 0 | [timestamp] |
| 25 | 2 | 1 | [timestamp] |

**orders**

| order_id (key) | order_info(varchar) | order_datetime(timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "info" | [timestamp] |
| 1 | "info" | [timestamp] |

Right now I retreive *order_info* and *order_datetime* from the orders table using the related *order_id* from task table, using this query.

```
WITH t AS (
        SELECT 
            task_id, 
            order_id,
            status
        FROM task_pool
        WHERE 
            task_id = $1 
            AND 
            (status = 0 OR status = 1)
    )
    SELECT  t.order_id, t.status,
            order_info, order_datetime
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN t ON orders.order_id=t.order_id`,
[req.body.task_id]
```

This works (the most efficient way, I don't know). It will only retrieve 1 row since task_id is  unique index key.

What I am trying to do, is check IF t.status=0, and if so UPDATE expire_time to expire_time + 10 minutes, and status to 1.

I know I COULD check the results.rows[0] back in Node.js, and if status==0, make another pg query to update that row's expire_time and status.

However, I would prefer to do it all in the original query, unless it unadvised.

Something like:

```
WITH t AS (
            SELECT 
                task_id, 
                order_id,
                status
            FROM task_pool
            WHERE 
                task_id = $1 
                AND 
                (status = 0 OR status = 1)
            )
**IF t.status = 0 THEN
    UPDATE 
        task_pool 
    SET 
        status = 1, expire_time = expire_time + (10 * interval '1 minute')
    WHERE
        task_id = $1
END IF;**

SELECT  t.order_id, t.status,
        order_info, order_datetime
FROM orders
INNER JOIN t ON orders.order_id=t.order_id`,
    [req.body.task_id]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you add the condition you want in `IF` as a `WHERE` condition?

Comment: You can trade your `select` for an `update..returning` that targets the same row, but updates it based on your conditions, then returns the new values: `update...set status=case when status=0 then 1 else status end, expire_time=case when status=0 then expire_time+'10 min'::interval else expire_time end where... returning task_id, order_id, status`

Answer (score 0):

You can trade your `select` for an [`update..returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.7) that targets the same row, but updates it based on your conditions, then returns the new values:

```sql
WITH t AS (
        UPDATE task_pool
        SET status=case when status=0 
                        then 1 
                        else status 
                   end, 
            expire_time=case when status=0 
                             then expire_time+'10 min'::interval 
                             else expire_time 
                        end
        WHERE 
            task_id = $1 
            AND 
            (status = 0 OR status = 1)
        RETURNING 
            task_id, 
            order_id,
            status
    )
    SELECT  t.order_id, t.status,
            order_info, order_datetime
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN t ON orders.order_id=t.order_id`,
[req.body.task_id]
```

You might want to decrease the table [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) to let it fit the new values on the same pages - even when the `update` is unnecessary, the row still gets updated with the same values (the `else`s).

---

You could also split this into two CTEs, one `select`, another with `update..returning`, then `union` those. That way no update is performed if it isn't necessary.

```sql
WITH t1 AS (
        UPDATE task_pool
        SET status=1, 
            expire_time=expire_time+'10 min'::interval 
        WHERE 
            task_id = $1 
            AND 
            status = 0
        RETURNING 
            task_id, 
            order_id,
            status
    )
,t2 AS (
        SELECT 
            task_id, 
            order_id,
            status
        FROM task_pool
        WHERE 
            task_id = $1 
            AND 
            status = 1
    )
,t AS (table t1 union table t2)
    SELECT  t.order_id, t.status,
            order_info, order_datetime
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN t ON orders.order_id=t.order_id`,
[req.body.task_id]
```

If your target row didn't meet the `update` criteria, that `update` is `returning` nothing, and the only values coming out of the `union` are those from the `select` which applied the opposite logic.

Comment: If you plan to paginate with a [`cursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html), there's also [`update...where current of "cursor"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).